# With Go's testing package is it possible to test what's printed to os.Stdout if part of the output is nondeterministic?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

I'm making a golang cli app using the github.com/codegangsta/cli package

I'm trying to test my app by calling app.Run(args) with invalid arguments. When running go test the output of the invalid arguments test is almost all deterministic except the USAGE section refers to go-build435629639 as part of the name of the executable (i.e. os.Args[0]) which is different each time.

Can I direct the output from app.Run into another io.writer without changing the cli package?

Can Examples with output specified be forced to skip over certain lines (or to only check the first line of output)?

Comment: For the first part, read the [documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/codegangsta/cli#ex-App). `cli.App` provides a `Writer` field that you can set to any `io.Writer` you'd like (e.g. a `bytes.Buffer`).

Comment: Thanks! Apologies I did look to see if one could be passed into Run but I should have looked at the App type.